# OctoberCMS : Prepare a URL for front end

Tags: php, twig, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have a component and I would like to prepare some URL.

The component display a list of categories, with a anchor tag for the category page. The category page can be selected in the component properties. After, the URL option is the slug.

For example, the category fruits : `http://mywebsite.com/category/fruits`.

I could do the following : `<a href="http://mywebsite.com/fruits/{{ category.slug }}">{{ category.name }}</a>` but this is not good, especially when I go to production.

For the page, I can use the `|page` filter with `{{ properties.categoryPage }}`, but I have to specifies the URL options, *slug*.

I think the best way would be to build a URL maker in the component PHP, but how?

Thanks.

Comment: Twig is very powerful. I can't see the need to create a component in PHP. What is the reason you can't use what you've shown above in Twig?

Comment: @AlvinBunk I did an error before, but now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following code works :

```
{{ properties.productPage|page({slug: category.slug }) }}
```